Can anyone help me to find the name of this Hollywood horror movie?
Several years ago, I watched only an intro of a horror movie. 
Unfortunately, I know almost NOTHING about the plot.
• General stuffs : Clearly was a Hollywood product, horror genre, made in period 2005-2013, main character was a famous girl, was about zombies
• First : The girl (main character) at the beginning sequence was making up in front of the mirror.
• Second : She had a mother who was a prostitute. I clearly remember in a sequence two guys wanted to sleep with her mother and then blamed her that her :censored: is getting loose. It was a dialogue from one of that two guys.
• Third : In another sequence a girl (who actually was a zombie) was riding on a guy and asked the guy to make his :censored: hard again. But the guy said he can't do it again. Then she got angry and turned a terrible zombie and killed (or hurt) the guy.

Its a porn movie?

@Marcio.Rezende, Absolutely not
